# Set correctly GridBagLayout constraints on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to code a part of my program by hand using GridBagLayout.
Im trying to get the three JLabels of the bottom of the first two components to be the same size, but, as you can see, "dd/mm/yyyy" and "author" labels are way closer than "State".

You can see how it looks here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEVu9.png]

This is some code of what i've made by far to get the result above.

```
        JButton btn;
        
        VotesView votesView = new VotesView();
        JScrollPane contentScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        JTextArea contentTxtArea = new JTextArea();
        JLabel datePostedLbl = new JLabel("dd/mm/yyyy", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel authorLbl = new JLabel("Author", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel stateLbl = new JLabel("State", JLabel.CENTER);
        
        /* add "Votes" (custom panel class) */
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        add(votesView, constraints);

        /* add JTextArea */
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        contentTxtArea.setMargin(new Insets(3,7,3,7));
        contentScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        contentTxtArea.setEditable(true);
        contentTxtArea.setColumns(20);
        contentTxtArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        contentTxtArea.setLineWrap(true);
        contentTxtArea.setRows(4);
        contentTxtArea.setText("Contenido");
        contentScrollPane.setViewportView(contentTxtArea);
        
        
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 1; // el texto de la respuesta tiene mas espacio en el panel
        add(contentScrollPane, constraints);
        
        /* add dd/mm/yyyy Label */
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        //constraints.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        add(datePostedLbl, constraints);
        
        /* add Author JLabel */
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        add(authorLbl, constraints);
        
         /* add State JLabel */
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        
        add(stateLbl, constraints);
```

Anyone could help me to get the three bottom JLabels aligned?

EDIT: Okay. I've used a Grid Layout on a new JPanel to have three columns and one row but the dateLbl places a "..." at the end. Should I set the sizes of the JLabels anyways (i need the date to be fully displayed)? I used a horizontal gap of 20 between the Labels.

```
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        JPanel answerInfoPane = new JPanel();
        answerInfoPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 20, 0));

        answerInfoPane.add(datePostedLbl);
        answerInfoPane.add(authorLbl);
        answerInfoPane.add(stateLbl);
        
        add(answerInfoPane, constraints);
```

This is the result adding the new Panel (using GridLayout) with the three JLabels in second row of the bigger panel using GridBagLayout

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg2ov.png]

FINAL EDIT: My bad. Just had to add the line of code "constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;". The JPanel wasn't using the available space and it looked centered. Now Looks just like I want:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ehx7.png]

Comment: A quote from [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html): _Not all rows necessarily have the same height. Similarly, not all columns necessarily have the same width._ Another quote: _Essentially, GridBagLayout places components in rectangles (cells) in a grid, and then uses the components' preferred sizes to determine how big the cells should be._ So maybe try to set the preferred sizes of the `JLabel`s.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656473/how-to-use-gridbaglayout

Comment: You're right. I'll try to set the preferred sizes of the JLabels tomorrow. Plus - thank you for the link in the 2nd comment, it seems pretty informative. I'll update this soon.

Comment: Don't use setPreferredSize(). Swing components will determine their own preferred size. You can always nest layout managers. If you want two components to be the same size, then you can use a JPanel with a GridLayout.

Comment: @camickr Hi! I did what you said and edited the code. Am I doing it correctly? Can u take a look at the code?  The frame looks like what I needed anyways, thank you.

Comment: @camickr My bad. I just had to add the line "constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;" to the constraints of the new JPanel with GridLayout. Now the panel fills all the empty space and all the labels are fully displayed. Thank you!